# In tkinter - how do I call a function using a button and output to the GUI?

Tags: tkinter

**Application with two buttons to call functions based on user preference**

Hello and thanks in advance for your help! I am a relative beginner with tkinter, and have worked through a few tutorials and a number of questions in stack overflow. However I have been unable to produce the output of a callback function *in* the GUI window after a button is pressed by the user. Code outlined below:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Crowdsourcing creativity')

    class Application(tk.Frame):
```

Below I have tried to create a fullscreen app that can be exited via the escape key

```
        def __init__(self, master=None):

            super().__init__(master)
            self.master = master
            pad=3
            master.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(
            master.winfo_screenwidth()-pad, master.winfo_screenheight()-pad))
            master.bind('<Escape>',self.close_window)
            self.pack()
            self.create_widgets()

        def close_window(self,event):
            root.destroy()
```

Next I have created two buttons

```
        def create_widgets(self):

            prompt_button = tk.Button(self,text = 'Do something', command=self.give_prompt).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            location_button = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go somewhere', command=self.give_location).pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
```

Finally I have tried to define the callback functions for the buttons. Note prompt() and location() refer to functions defined earlier in the code (the essentially return a random item from their respective lists).

```
        def give_prompt(self):

            label1 = Label(self, prompt())
            label1.pack()

        def give_location(self):

            label2 = Label(self, location())
            label2.pack()

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

The output currently appears in the terminal where I run the code, rather than the GUI. I would also like the original buttons to disappear when clicked, so that the output is the only thing remaining in the GUI. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It's nearly there.  You need the two Label creations to be `tk.Label`, not simply `Label`.  Each button click will then create a new tk.Label.

Comment: Thanks @TlsChris! I now have a working application

Answer (score 0):

Use tk.Label.

Or instead of importing tkinter, Do this :

`from tkinter import *`